# Limited width line around title

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a title with lines around created with CSS grid. I would like the lines to be smaller (saying 5%)
How can I achieve this?

HTML and CSS

```css
h1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(20px, 1fr) auto minmax(20px, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 3.4em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
}

h1:before,
h1:after {
  content: '';
  border-top: 2px solid #ff3f3f;
}
```

```html
<h1>Text</h1>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using CSS Grid, you can use `display: flex;` along with `justify-content: center` to achieve this. The `:before` and `:after` get a (max-)width and some `margin` to make sure they don't touch the heading.

```css
h1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3.4em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
}

h1:before,
h1:after {
  content: '';
  border-top: 2px solid #ff3f3f;
  width: 5%;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Text</h1>
```